# Conditional Lexicographical Permutations

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

So I have read on algorithms that can generate lexicographical permutations.
Such as: 1-2-3-4-5->1-2-3-5-4->1-2-4-3-5->...->5-4-3-2-1

However I would like to impose some boolean condition where I skip some permutations.

Suppose I have:
1-2-3-4-5
1-2-3-5-4
.
.
.
and I want to skip all other 1-2-X-X-X
and go to 1-3-2-4-5

Would swapping 2 and 3 and sorting the remaining three numbers be the best way of doing so?
Or is there another way that could be faster?

Comment: What types of boolean condition do you want to use? The one you proposed looks like this: If already generated (1,2,3,4,5) and (1,2,3,5,4) then if beginning of currently generated permutation is (1,2) then skip. Describe boolean conditions you want to use.

Comment: So for numbers 1,2,3,4,5 I have 5! permutations.
For permutations with 1-2 in front I have 3! permutations of that type.

I would like to impose a boolean condition such that when the front two numbers add up to 3 I skip all other permutations of type 1-2-X-X-X and go to 1-3-2-4-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't really understand your question but from what I see you could base on this piece of code:

```
vector<int> permutation;
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
   permutation.push_back(i);
void gen_perm(int level, vector<int>& per){
  if (level < N-1);
    for (int i = level; i < N; ++i) {
        swap(per[level], per[i]);
        gen_perm(level + 1, per);
        swap(per[level], per[i]);
    }
  else
    print(per) or return per or whatever you want to do with perms.
}
```

And now, what about conditions? You could pass them to gen_perm function as for example vector of pointers to functions that returns bool and takes level and permutation (reference) and if condition fails at given level then return without doing anything, so let's say you could create a fun like this:

```
bool check_3(int level, vector<int>& perm) {
   if (level == 2)
      if (perm[0] + perm[1] == 3) return false;
   return true;
}
```

I advice you to first:

```
typedef bool (*cond_fun)(int, vector<int>&);
```

the use them in gen_loop like that for example:

```
void gen_perm(int level, vector<int>& per, vector<cond_fun>& conds){
  if (level < N-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < conds.size(); ++i) {
       if (!(*conds[i])(level, per)) return;
    }
    for (int i = level; i < N; ++i) {
        swap(per[level], per[i]);
        gen_perm(level + 1, per, conds);
        swap(per[level], per[i]);
    }
  else
    print(per) or return per or whatever you want to do with perms.
}
```

Of course you can improve it if you have additional knowledge like: each condition can fail one time maximum so you can erase them from vector if they return false.

Comment: Well I am trying to use permutations applied to the context of branch and bound. So for each number: 1, 2, 3,... I would have a corresponding "cost" and I would like to prune early one if the cumulative "cost" of a partial permutation exceeds my limit. Once a partial permutation exceeds my limit, I don't want to compute other permutations of that form. I want to skip to the next partial permutation.

Comment: So in the example I stated, if the cumulative cost with the numbers 1-2 has already exceeded my limit I just want to generate the permutation for 1-3 as I don't want to waste time computing 1-2-3-4-5, 1-2-3-5-4, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your contribute but for me he issue is how to formulate a routine that allows QUICK transition from a partial permutation to the next order, say from 1-2-X-X-X to 1-3-2-4-5 or 1-2-4-3-5 to 1-2-5-3-4.

Comment: @XYZ this is what my code does...
How does this costs connects to position in permutation?

Comment: Your code does not show how you would skip from some permutation say 1-2-4-3-5 -> 1-3-2-4-5.

Comment: If you will give a proper condition to it then it will do exactly this skip. That's why I asked you to explain in detail that cost - limit thing, if you don't provide all necessary parts building an efficient algorithm is impossible.

Comment: Alright, so assume in this case that the "cost" that I am talking about is the sum of the first two numbers. So we let the limit "cost" k be equal to 4. In this case, we should not get any permutations of this form: 1-3-X-X-X or 3-1-X-X-X.

Comment: After I transition from 1-2-5-4-3 to 1-3-2-4-5, I will evaluate the sum of the first two numbers. It will be 4. 

As such I want to skip all permutations with 1-3-X-X-X.

I am asking about an efficient way to do this. I see you including a  functor but you haven't shown how to perform the transition.

What I had in mind was that I would swap the next guy '4' in our case, swap it with the '3' and sort the numbers -2-3-5 so I get the next order 1-4-2-3-5.

I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: The gen_perm routine that you typed out relies on swapping numbers around a "permutation" vector. As such you cannot simply ERASE the number. You would have to find the next number, swap it with the current one. Then rearrange the sub-vector in increasing order.

Comment: Sorry, but I missed the part that you want them lexicographically ordered (you missed this word in problem statement...). My code generates permutations not ordered in any way, but it can skip over entire prefix-permutations like 1-3 to the next one (I believe it will be 1-4). But if you want lex sorted permutations then yes after each 'skip' in my opinion the most efficient way is to sort remaining part of vector and continue algorithm (the one described on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order).

Comment: In this algorithm sorting rest of the vector is needed to maintain algorithm invariant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28135/discussion-between-xyz-and-piotr-jaszkowski)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is called a factorial base, and you could just advance the counter with the correct amount when needed. You can read more about it here: http://efesx.com/2009/11/14/enumerating-permutations/ (and at http://marknelson.us/2002/03/01/next-permutation/ as well)